# Questions on HERE Batch Geocoding - How long does it take for HERE Batch Geocoding to complete - Stuck in Accepted Status

Tags: here-api

I was testing and doing a POC for HERE Batch Geocoding I have a few questions regarding it.

HERE Batch Geocoding **request is stuck in accepted status for nearly half an hour** while it does have like 5 lines of the address to geocode in POST Body,

I have a few questions regarding HERE Batch Geocoding as follows

======================================================================

1. **How long will it take for HERE Batch Geocoding** to provide a
   response?
2. Does hitting Batch Geocode JobStatus API /job/requestID
   add up in the count at time of **billing**?
3. If Yes - **Is there a push
   model / webhook** where users can subscribe to the changes to the job?
4. Can we get the result response in JSON instead of zip/text files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Batch job response times depend on the load of the system. It can be done within a minute, but can also take longer.
- Billing is done based on the backend geocode calls, asking for the status is free.
- There is no callback available for the end of job.
- Use 'outputcompressed' to get a straight text response without compression. See https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/dev_guide/topics/request-parameters.html

Comment: Freemium and Pro plans have the same priority when running batch jobs?